# How to create directories for dist files?

Tags: gnu-make

Here's my Makefile:

```
dist/%.js: src/%.js node_modules
    $(NM)/babel $< -o $@

build: $(patsubst src/%,dist/%,$(wildcard src/**/*.js))
```

It runs a command like this:

```
node_modules/.bin/babel src/deep/foo.js -o dist/deep/foo.js
```

The problem is that if `dist/deep` doesn't exist, it errors:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'dist/deep/foo.js'

So what I want to do is add an extra dependency on the directory, which I was hoping I could do with something like this:

```
dist/%.js: src/%.js $(dir dist/%) node_modules
    $(NM)/babel $< -o $@

dist/%/:
    mkdir -p $@

build: $(patsubst src/%,dist/%,$(wildcard src/**/*.js))
```

But it doesn't work. `$(dir dist/%)` isn't filling in that `%` like I hoped. Running `make --trace` yields:

```
Makefile:10: update target 'dist/deep/foo.js' due to: src/deep/foo.js dist/ node_modules
```

i.e., you can see it has a dependency on `dist/`, but I was hoping it'd depend on `dist/deep/` so that I could `mkdir -p` it.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a subsidiary snag. Judging from:

```
$(wildcard src/**/*.js)
```

it seems you want this function to perform recursive globbing,
returning all `*.js` files that exist in `src` or any subdirectory
thereof.

I don't know what shell you've got, but they don't all do that by
default. The linux `bash` shell doesn't, though as of `bash` 4.0
it will do it if the shell option `globstar` is set.

And anyway, `$(wildcard ...)` won't do it (unless, possibly, the
operative shell does it by default, which I'm not in a position to
check out). So you can't dependably use `$(wildcard ...)` for that
purpose. You need `make` to be invoking a shell in which recursive
`**` globbing is enabled, and then call:

```
$(shell ls src/**/*.js)
```

So that's what I'll do now in showing how to solve your problem with
a simple example. I've got:

```
src/
    one.js
    a/
        two.js
        c/
            four.js
    b/
        three.js
```

and I just want to each `*.js` file copied from beneath `src` to the
same relative name under `dist`, ensuring that `dist` and all
necessary subdirectories exist when required to. (Of course, this
could all be done at once with `cp`). Here is a makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
.SHELLFLAGS := -O globstar -c

SRCS := $(shell ls src/**/*.js)
DISTS := $(patsubst src/%,dist/%,$(SRCS))
DESTDIRS := $(dir $(DISTS))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(DISTS)

dist/%.js: src/%.js | $(DESTDIRS)
    cp $< $@

$(DESTDIRS):
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    rm -fr dist
```

which runs like:

```
$ make
mkdir -p dist/a/c/
mkdir -p dist/b/
cp src/a/c/four.js dist/a/c/four.js
cp src/a/two.js dist/a/two.js
cp src/b/three.js dist/b/three.js
cp src/one.js dist/one.js
```

In that makefile,

```
| $(DESTDIRS)
```

makes each of the `$(DESTDIRS)` an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)
of any target `dist/%.js`. An order-only prequisite is not considered in determining whether its
target shall be made, but if it is determined that the target shall be made, then the
order-only prequisite will be made first.

Comment: You're right that my `wildcard` wasn't working like I hoped. I was only testing with files exactly 1 level deep, and it works for that specific case. I'm actually using `zsh` which does support the `**/*` globbing, but I think `$(shell find src -name '*.js')` might be more versatile? Thank you for explaining order-only prereqs. I've seen those before, but I could never wrap my head around what they actually do. This looks like it's working the way I want now, thank you!! Only problem is I'm getting a warning now, "target 'dist/' given more than once in the same rule".

Comment: I think sorting will fix that though `DISTDIRS := $(sort $(dir $(DISTS)))`